# Wget crawling problem

Tags: wget

I've seen that in order to crawl an entire website, this command should work :

```
wget  --spider -r https://wikipedia.org/
```

But my question is why the same command to crawl an entire website, doesn't work with wikipedia ?

My goal is not to crawl all wikiepdia but to know the difference.

This is the output of the command:

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2016-08-31 17:53:56--  http://wikipedia.org/
Resolving wikipedia.org (wikipedia.org)... 91.198.174.192, 2620:0:862:ed1a::1
Connecting to wikipedia.org (wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 TLS Redirect
Location: https://wikipedia.org/ [following]
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2016-08-31 17:53:56--  https://wikipedia.org/
Connecting to wikipedia.org (wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.wikipedia.org/ [following]
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2016-08-31 17:53:56--  https://www.wikipedia.org/
Resolving www.wikipedia.org (www.wikipedia.org)... 91.198.174.192, 2620:0:862:ed1a::1
Connecting to www.wikipedia.org (www.wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain links to other resources -- retrieving.

--2016-08-31 17:53:56--  https://www.wikipedia.org/
Reusing existing connection to www.wikipedia.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘wikipedia.org/index.html’

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ] 81 292      --.-K/s   in 0,03s   

2016-08-31 17:53:57 (2,44 MB/s) - ‘wikipedia.org/index.html’ saved [81292]

Removing wikipedia.org/index.html.

Found no broken links.

FINISHED --2016-08-31 17:53:57--
Total wall clock time: 0,2s
Downloaded: 1 files, 79K in 0,03s (2,44 MB/s)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an FAQ (for both `wget` and Wikipedia):

- [4.4. How can I make Wget ignore the robots.txt file/no-follow attribute?](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_can_I_make_Wget_ignore_the_robots.txt_file.2Fno-follow_attribute.3F)

> By default, Wget plays the role of a web-spider that plays nice, and obeys a site's `robots.txt` file and [**`no-follow`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow) attributes.

- [nofollow](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Nofollow)

> On 18 January 2005 the Google blog entry "Preventing comment spam" declared that Google would henceforth respect a **`rel="nofollow"`** attribute on hyperlinks. Their page ranking algorithm now ignores links with this attribute when ranking the destination page. The intended result is that site administrators can modify user-posted links such that the attribute is present, and thus an attempt to googlebomb by posting a link on such a site would yield no increase from that link.

The point is that Wikipedia has setup the site to discourage you from doing this.